# How to use equal and not equal together in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to select values from three tables. First table is `sale_project_detail`, the second table is `design_project_detail`, and the third table is `design_designer`.

`sale_project_detail` schema:

```
Id int,
Name nvarchar(50),
ShortDescription nvarchar(max)
```

`design_project_assignment` schema:

```
Id int,
DId int (It is foreign key of design_designer table),
SPId int (It is foreign key of sale_project_detail table),
AssignDateTime datetime,
DueDate date,
Status varchar(10)
```

`design_designer` schema:

```
Id int,
Name nvarchar(15)
```

Now, I have to select complete detail from `sale_project_detail`

```
where assign_project_detail.SPId <> sale_project_detail.Id,
```

and

```
Select design_designer(Name) 
from design_designer 
where design_designer.Id = assign_project_detail.DId
```

I am trying below code, but it is returning wrong result.

My code:

```
SELECT
   sale_project_detail.*,
   design_project_assignment.*,
   design_designer.Name
FROM
   sale_project_detail,
   design_project_assignment,
   design_designer
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
              FROM design_project_assignment
              LEFT JOIN design_designer ON design_designer.Id = design_project_assignment.DId
              WHERE sale_project_detail.Id = design_project_assignment.SPId)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have not joined your tables

Comment: select t1.col1, t2.col1, t1.col2 from table1 join table2 on table2.fk_id = table1.id

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style should **no longer be used** and instead it is recommended to use the **proper ANSI JOIN** syntax introduced with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago). Because you're using the legacy style and you're **not** providing any join conditions, you're getting a **cartesian product** between your three tables!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
   sale_project_detail as spd 
   inner join design_project_assignment dpa on dpa.spid <> spd.id
   inner join design_designer dd on dd.id = dpa.did;
```